# Gmail Custom Domain Email is able to send mail but cannot receive it

Tags: email, dns, gmail, mx-record

I have an issue where I have a custom domain set up with gmail, I have all DNS pointing to the correct location as defined in the google documentation (4 hours is the smallest TTL my DNS allows me to assign):

[image: mx records list]

I have already set up gmail in google admin, and that all seems correct to me.

The weird thing is that if I send email from the account admin@mycustomdomain.com I can send it and the recipient will receive it.

However if they try to respond, they get an error from Mail Delivery Subsystem saying that it is not delivered, and it never appears in the admin@mycustomdomain.com email address.

Does anyone know what I'm missing? I've made sure that there are no extra MX records that could be messing this up in my DNS as well. I have been googling around about it but I am not finding anything I haven't tried already and am not sure how to debug this.

Comment: I've found an article saying that gmail was having this outage but it says it was fixed on the 15th, why am I still getting this issue? anyone know? https://9to5google.com/2020/12/15/gmail-address-not-found/

Comment: What is the output of the command `host -t mx mycostomdomain.com` ?
Exact error message from mail delivery system also will be helpful.